# Можно ли в open server работать с сокетами?

Tags: php, сокет, websocket, openserver

Пробовал запустить socket сервер, но выходят ошибки. Поддерживает ли php в open sever сокеты? И что нужно сделать, чтобы работать с ними в нем?

Answer (score 2):

Да, можно. Вам нужно подключить расширение `php_sockets.dll`, для этого раскомментируйте соответствующую строку в конфигурационном файле `php.ini`:

```
;extension=php_sockets.dll
```

И после этого перезагрузите ваш сервер.

Затем вы можете запустить функцию `extension_loaded()` и проверить, подключилось ли это расширение:

```php
if (extension_loaded('sockets') === false) {
    throw new Exception('Error');
} else {
    echo 'Success';
}
```